# Powershell, Select one value from excel autofilter

Tags: powershell

I'm needing help where I wanted powershell to open up excel select a value from the filter, then save and e-mail.
All the other stuff is easy and works just fine, but I can't find the correct script to select a vlaue from an filter in excel?
The filter is already applied, I just need it to select it.

```
  $localpath ="C:\PowerShellScripts\"
 $localfilename =  "Q:\Dynamic Reports\test.xlsx"
 $xl = new-object -c excel.application
 #Start Logging
 Start-Transcript -Path $errorlog -Append
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
 set-itemProperty -Path $localfilename -Name IsReadOnly -Value $false
$app = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$app.Visible = $True

 set-itemProperty -Path $localfilename -Name IsReadOnly -Value $false
$wb = $app.Workbooks.Open("Q:\Dynamic Reports\test.xlsx")

Set-Clipboard
Start-Sleep 10
$wb.Name
$wb.RefreshAll()
Start-Sleep 50
$ws = $wb.Sheets.Item("Shortlife")
$wb.Save()
$wb.Close()
$app.Quit()
```

Comment: Hi, can you share some of your code, then your issue will be more clear

Comment: sure, thing, I updated the post.